# Replace a pattern for every line which starts with another pattern

Tags: sed, replace

In the below example, I have to replace AB with CD for every line starting with SEG+BB

SEG+AA+AB `SEG+BB+6789+AB12345`
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345 `SEG+BB+6789+AB12345`
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345 `SEG+BB+6789+AB12345`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Could you please do add 3 simple things in your question. 1st- Clear sample of input, 2nd- clear sample of output and 3rd- your tried commands/code, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  
 i am getting the below error
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13

In the below example, I have to replace AB with CD for every line starting with SEG+BB


INPUT  
SEG+AA+AB  
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345  
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345  
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345   
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345  
SEG+BB+6789+AB12345  

OUTPUT  
SEG+AA+AB  
SEG+BB+6789+CD12345  
SEG+BB+6789+CD12345  
SEG+BB+6789+CD12345   
SEG+BB+6789+CD12345    
SEG+BB+6789+CD12345

`    sed 's/^(SEG+BB;([^;]+;){5})AB;/\CD;/'    `

I

Answer (score 0):

> I have to replace AB with CD for every line starting with SEG+BB

This code do the work:

```
sed '/^SEG+BB/ { s/AB/CD/g }'
```

**'/^SEG+BB/ { }'** => for all lines starting with "SEG+BB", do code inside brackets